Using initializer lists in a parameter pack and avoiding template deduction errors
I'm trying to emulate the array slicing syntax of FORTRAN in C++, and am running into the following issue. In FORTRAN, multidimensional arrays can be sliced like a(1,2,1:5:2), meaning 1st element of 1st dimension, 2nd element of 2nd dimension, elements 1-5 (inclusive) with a stride of 2 for the third dimension. I guess doing this verbatim is not possible since the : character is reserved, but I was hoping that a(1,2,{1,5,2}) would be possible.
If I have an Array class like

template<int D>
class Array {
  ...
}


auto a3d = Array<3>(nx,ny,nz); 


then the above slice would produce a 1D array (i.e. Array<1>). Therefore, in the slicing operator, I need to deduce at compile time how many dimensions are removed and how many are kept. I had this problem answered in Deducing number of arguments in a parameter pack, so I can have an overload of operator () that looks like
template <typename T,typename... Ts>
struct count {
    static const unsigned value = (std::is_same_v<T,Ts> + ...);
};

class Slice { 
    public: 
        const int start, end, stride; 

        Slice(int i): start(i), end(i), stride(1){};
        Slice(int i, int j) : start(i), end(j), stride(1){};
        Slice(int i, int j, int k) : start(i), end(j), stride(k){};
        
};

template<typename... Ts> 
auto Array::operator () (Ts... ts){ 
  
    constexpr int num_fixed_dims = count<int,Ts...>::value; 
    auto slices = {Slice(ts)...}; 
    Array<D - num_fixed_dims> sliced_array(slices); 

    return sliced_array; 
}


The problem I'm now having is that

a(1,2,{1,5,2})


gives a compiler error
<source>:20:6: note: candidate template ignored: substitution failure: deduced incomplete pack <int, int, (no value)> for template parameter 'Ts'
       ^    

when calling Array::operator ().
Something like

a(1,2,std::array{1,5,2})


has no such template deduction issues, and could work, but I feel it is aesthetically displeasing and burdensome to have to call std::array or some other constructor everywhere. Is there any way around this?
Minimum example: https://godbolt.org/z/h8nf63z6d. The second call is what I'd like to have compile.

Provide a [mcve]. Something the can be copy/pasted into the compiler etc and reproduce the error.

Brace-init list is non-deduced context; it doesn't have a type, and doesn't participate in type deduction. You'd have to write a(1,2, Slice{1,5,2}) or similar.

C++20 has std::span. C++23 has std::mdspan.
